# Polymer 2 client runtime error

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

I installed polymer using the recommended syntax:
`npm install -g polymer-cli@next`

I created a polymer 2 element using the `polymer init` interface.

The issue I'm having is when I run `polymer serve`, I get the following error:

```
error:   cli runtime exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
error:   SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymercli/node_modules/polyserve/lib/start_server.js:33:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)`
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling polymer, but getting the same issue. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my polymer client error.

It turns out the new version of polymer required node v6 or higher.. barely noticed that notice message when I installed.